# Navbar pushes DIV's off screen

Tags: html, css

The purple Navbar at the top of the page pushes the container "container2" off screen. Is there any possible way I can make it so the "container2" div does not overflow with the proper padding of 5px at the bottom?

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gugi&display=swap');

/*QuickReset*/ * { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; }

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

body {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
    background: purple;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}

.navbar .logo {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Gugi', cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
}

.navbar .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
    justify-content: unset;
}

.navbar nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: none;
    position: unset;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.container2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    gap: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.one,
.two {
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.one { width: 10%; background: red;  }
.two { width: 90%; background: blue; }
```

```html
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="logo" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <div class="one">
        </div>
        <div class="two">
        </div>
    </div>
```

> Resulting Page

[image: resulting page]

I am new to HTML and CSS so any helps greatly appreciated.

Stack overflow wants more content besides code but im not too sure what else to add.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow: hidden` from `body`:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gugi&display=swap');

/*QuickReset*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%
}

body {
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.navbar {
  background: purple;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.navbar .logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Gugi', cursive;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: white;
}

.navbar .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
  justify-content: unset;
}

.navbar nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: none;
  position: unset;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.one,
.two {
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.one {
  width: 10%;
  background: red;
}

.two {
  width: 90%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="logo" href="#">Logo</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container2">
  <div class="one">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would live the "container2" div to fit on the screen without having to scroll to get all of it in view.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Gugi&display=swap');

/*QuickReset*/ * { box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; }

body {
  background: black;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
    background: purple;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    height: 20%;
}

.navbar .logo {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Gugi', cursive;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    color: white;
}

.navbar .container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100px auto;
    justify-content: unset;
}

.navbar nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background: none;
    position: unset;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}

.container2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    position: relative;
    gap: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.one,
.two {
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.one { width: 10%; background: red;  }
.two { width: 90%; background: blue; }
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="logo" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container2">
        <div class="one">
        </div>
        <div class="two">
        </div>
    </div>
```

you should divide the height of navbar and container 2

Comment: Changing the height on container2 to a lower percentage will fix the problem, except now there is padding on the bottom of much more than 5px. I calculated the exact percentage to be 89.234% but I feel like its a bad practice to use that method.